# Should the result be consistent if using Limit without Order By in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Should the result be consistent if using Limit without Order By in MySQL, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM LARGE_TABLE LIMIT 1000, 10;
```

I am using PHP, so option such as discussed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374035/is-it-correct-to-scan-a-table-in-mysql-using-select-limit-start-count-wit) cannot be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not guaranteed to be consistent. the results may defer from time to time (but this is not guaranteed either)

Comment: Even though this question is 100% right, in mysql it is possible with `ALTER TABLE` to phisically resort the data in data file so `SELECTs` without `order by` will always return the same result set.

Comment: @zerkms, do you mean? ALTER TABLE LARGE_TABLE ORDER BY id?

Comment: @Howard: yep. But my comment is "bad" comment - you should never rely on the result set retrieved without `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @zerkms, yes, but seems no other way to walk thru my large table. Order by is not possible since it is too slow. Thanks anyway.